# Clickable hashtags and users in label

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project where users post and can tag users. Users are tagged with @username and tags are made with #tagname

For example if the body is

> Hello World @ExampleUser #ExampleTag

The posts are binded to a listview to the following template.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TextPostTemplate">
            <local:PostViewCell>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 10, 10">
                    . . .
                    <Label Text="{Binding Body}" . . ./>
                    . . .
                </StackLayout>
            </local:PostViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
```

But I can't find out how to make the tags and users clickable and also have the attribute bold so they stand out.

I know about custom renderers to make URL's clickable but I don't know how to edit them to make it look for words starting with @ and #. Then once clicked open UserPage(username) or TagPage(tagname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't do it out of the box in Xamarin Forms. Take a look at this article [Creating a HyperlinkLabel in Xamarin Forms](https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/11/05/creating-a-hyperlinklabel-in-xamarin-forms/), it has details how to do it using custom renderers for iOS. It seems to support UWP by default and you would need to implement Android by yourself also.